# Appending a string with a format like number&sound in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I return an appended string in a format like number$sound and then when it get returned, break up the string into two pieces again like (the number and then the sound filename) in objective-c

Comment: Show a bit of code for what you have tried. Show the source and desired result string content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**integer version:**

```
int number = 10;    
NSString *sound = @"sound";
NSString *combinedString =
  [sound stringByAppendingString:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d$%@",number,sound]];
```

**String Version:**

```
NSString *number = @"10";    
NSString *sound = @"sound";    
NSString *combinedString = 
  [sound stringByAppendingString:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@$%@",number,sound]];
```

**Output: 10$sound**

```
NSArray *combinedObjects  = [combinedString componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];    
NSString *mynumber=[combinedObjects objectAtIndex:0];//10    
NSString *mysound= [combinedObjects objectAtIndex:1];//sound
```

Comment: And how to break up the strings in to two pieces again like (the number and then the sound filename) ?  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Did u see my code after "Output: 10$sound"? thats what you want.

Comment: Yes I did, but I can't make it work. Let me explain my situation here. So I have an array of images that are numbers and an array of sounds that are the sounds of numbers, now I want to append them together in one array and then separate them again. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: int number = 10;    
int sound = 20;
NSString *combinedString =
  [sound stringByAppendingString:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d$%d",number,sound]];

Answer (score 0):

To separate a `NSString` by `$`

```
NSArray* separatedString = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];
```