# How to break up a string into two pieces from an array in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

The arrays are images and I need to add the sound array with it so I can show it in a button and when the button is clicked it will show the image and play the sound.
I used `componentsJoinedByString` method to format the array with this sign `($)`.
I use `stringByAppendingSting` method to add them together, so I guess that i need to format the strings so I can break them a part again.

```
NSArray  *rankNum = [PlayingCard rankNumbers];
[rankNum componentsJoinedByString:@"$"];
NSArray  *rankCol = [PlayingCard rankColors];
NSArray  *rankAni = [PlayingCard rankAnimals];

switch (self.chosenButton) {
    case 0:
        return [rankNum[self.rank] stringByAppendingString:self.sound];
        break;
    case 1:
        return rankCol[self.rank];
        break;
    case 2:
        return rankAni[self.rank];
        break;
    default:
        // It should not get here
        return nil;
        break;
```

**This is the array of sound :**

```
   + (NSArray *) rankNumSound
{
    NSArray *getNumSound = [[[SoundModel alloc] init]getSoundNumbers];
    return getNumSound;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you have at the beginning, and what you want at the end? Because, that's quite strange. An array of images, you mean "name" of images?

Comment: Explain your query clearly..

Comment: Both are strings or images?

Comment: Your question is very vague, elaborate a bit more!

Comment: This sounds very similar to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247802/appending-a-string-with-a-format-like-numbersound-in-ios (for which you accepted an answer).

Comment: Why a string? Use a dictionary or custom container class.

Comment: For me it looks like you didn't really try it or search for an existing answer

Comment: Have you bothered to look at the documentation for NSString???

Comment: I have updated my question. sorry guys for my lack of explaining. My English is not that good. I'm also new to pretty new in programming. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
NSMutableArray *arrayResult = [NSMutableArray array];
//you should to fill your arrays with your sounds and images
NSMutableArray *arrayImages = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *arraySound = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < [arrayImages count]-1; i++) {

    [arrayResult addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@$%@", [arrayImages objectAtIndex:i], [arraySound objectAtIndex:i]]];

}

NSMutableArray *newArrayimages = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *newArraySound = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < [arrayResult count]; i++) {

    NSArray *arrayResultString = [NSMutableArray array];

    arrayResultString = [[arrayResult objectAtIndex:i]componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];

    [newArrayimages addObject:[arrayResultString objectAtIndex:0]];
    [newArraySound addObject:[arrayResultString objectAtIndex:1]];

}
```

Comment: This will exclude the last entry in arrayImages and arrayResult. The for test should be i < [arrayResult count]. Apart from that, it should work as the OP requests.

Comment: Why do I have to loop in the images? is it to add the dollar sign in the strings?

Comment: Do loop to your imageArray or soundArray, as you like more. its because you need to loop as many times as images or sounds you have. I guess you have the same images and sounds. And yes Marius Falkenberg Waldal, you are right, I updated it